# How can I configure Manjaro in GRUB2 without re-running the Manjaro installer?

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, kernel-panic, manjaro

I reinstalled the Ubuntu boot-loader one day, and it showed an entry for Manjaro, but it kernel panicked on boot.

After re-running the Manjaro installer, the kernel was fixed, but GRUB ignored Ubuntu.

I recently installed OpenSUSE and the same predicament is occurring again; so how would I go about fixing this kernel panic without having to reinstall GRUB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possibly considered as a bug, but for Manjaro perhaps it is a feature, making **Manjaro** the prefered boot OS for your system.  A panic situation occurs when it gets upset by another installer.

I remember hearing on the [Linux Luddites](https://linuxluddites.com/shows/episode-9/) podcast that the Manjaro installer does something similar to this, perhaps on purpose.

It is ***directly [addressed by the Majaro team, here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kernel-panic/1616/13)***, in a very involved discussion, which doesn't seem quite resolved, even yet.

You have to [restore GRUB](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/creating-a-new-os-independent-grub-2-bootloader/3150) in one way or [another](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/creating-a-new-os-independent-grub-2-bootloader/3150) (for just a couple of examples), after installation, if you do not like this behavior.